# How to add element to embeds_many field of mongoid model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have embeds_many field `:items` in model (mongoid)

```
class Course
  embeds_many :items

  def create_item
    item = Item.new
    update_attributes items, items | [item]
  end
end
```

...

```
c = Course.new
item = c.create_item
```

Which is right way add new element in `:items`? I try use `update_attributes items, items | [item]` but i think that is ugly approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`embeds_many` supports the usual set of methods that ActiveRecord's `has_many` does so you can say things like:

```
def create_item
  items.create(args)
end
```

just like you would with an AR `has_many`.